# Replace text between brackets

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regular-expression, replace

I'm using `awk '{ gsub(/BAR|WIBBLE/, "FOO"); print }'` to replace text in data like:

```
SOMETHING [BAR, WIBBLE]
SOMETHING [BAR]
```

This gives the desired result of:

```
SOMETHING [FOO, FOO]
SOMETHING [FOO]
```

But now I've had to update the text that requires replacing to be something like:

```
awk '{ gsub(/BAR|WIBBLE|ME/, "FOO"); print }'
```

Which turns text like:

```
SOMETHING [ME, WIBBLE]
```

into:

```
SOFOOTHING [FOO, FOO]
```

How can I limit my replacement to just the text between the brackets (i.e. leave the `SOMETHING` alone)?

**EDIT**

I also need robustness across whatever text `SOMETHING` might be (e.g. `SHE GAVE ME THAT` shouldn't have `ME` replaced).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Must that be `awk`? Is much easier in other languages where the substitution's replacement part can be a function call. For example `perl`:

```
perl -pe 'sub c{$s=shift;$s=~s/BAR|WIBBLE|ME/FOO/g;$s}s/\[.*?\]/c$&/ge'
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. @choroba and @Guru word boundary would have been great too, but I want to be robust in what text the `SOMETHING` should be. I'll update the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk you can set `RS` to the contents of brackets and then do the replacement on `RT` (matched record separator):

```
awk -v RS='\\[[^]]*\\]' '{ gsub(/\<(BAR|WIBBLE|ME)\>/, "FOO", RT); printf "%s%s", $0, RT }' infile
```

infile:

```
cat << EOF > infile
SHE GAVE ME THAT
SOMETHING [ME, WIBBLE, SOMMER]
EOF
```

output:

```
SHE GAVE ME THAT
SOMETHING [FOO, FOO, SOMMER]
```

Comment: +12. That RT trick is wicked!

Answer (score 2):

Awk lacks backreferences in regular expression replacements, so it can't easily do replacements in context. Sed can do it:

```
sed -e 's/\(\[[^]]*\)BAR/\1FOO/' 's/\(\[[^]]*\)ME/\1FOO/'
```

If your sed supports alternations in regexps:

```
sed -e 's/\(\[[^]]*\)\(BAR\|ME\)/\1FOO/'
```

This only handles a single replacement inside each bracket pair, even with the `g` suffix, because `[^]]*` matches the longest close-bracket-free sequence. To replace all of them, use an explicit loop; note that this only works if `FOO` isn't a substring of `BAR` or `ME`.

```
sed -e ': a' -e 's/\(\[[^]]*\)BAR/\1FOO/' -e 't a' \
             -e 's/\(\[[^]]*\)ME/\1FOO/' -e 't a'
```

If you need something more complicated, [use perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52796).

Answer (score -3):

```
awk '{ gsub(/\bBAR\b|\bWIBBLE\b|\bME\b/, "FOO"); print }'
```