# Delete text between patterns occurring in different lines

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I know that [similar questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52793/replace-text-between-brackets) have been asked on this forum but, as far as I can see, none of them addressed the problem of patterns being in different lines. Namely, given a text file

```
( one ) ( two ) (

three

)

four
```

How may I delete everything that is between each '(' and ')' pair, even when the elements of the pair are on different lines? The desired result is

```
() () ()

four
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl: slurp the whole input as a single string, and use the `s` flag on the `s///` command to indicate the newlines are to be treated as plain characters:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\(.*?\)/()/sg' <<END
( one ) ( two ) (

three

)

four
END
```

```
() () ()

four
```

Comment: Does this treat STDIN as a stream or read it all into memory?  Also, is `-0777` actually required?  It's working without that flag for me.

Comment: It reads it into memory, and the -0777 option is required here. You'll have to demonstrate what you're doing to prove to me it isn't.

Comment: Ah-ha!  So if you pass the string like this: `< <(echo 'something...`)` then it works without -0777 flag, but when passing to stdin with a heredoc the flag is needed for it to work.  Thanks Glenn.

Comment: In your process substitution, do you have any newlines? Or just a single echo statement?

Comment: Slight correction: I used `echo -e ...`

Comment: So if there are no newlines in the input then that option has no visible effect

Comment: Understood, thanks for patiently educating me Glenn!  Cheers, Jay

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a simple state machine in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import fileinput
import sys

active = True
for line in fileinput.input():
    for ch in line:
        if ch == '(':
            sys.stdout.write(ch)
            active = False
        elif ch == ')':
            sys.stdout.write(ch)
            active = True
        elif active:
            sys.stdout.write(ch)
```

[Runnable Solution](http://tpcg.io/9qWDxV)

Usage:

```
$ echo '( one ) ( two ) (

three

)

four' | python /tmp/statemachine.py
```

Output:

```
() () ()

four
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Python`** alternative:

```
python -c 'import sys,re; print(re.sub(r"\([^()]+\)","()",sys.stdin.read().strip()))' <file
```

The output:

```
() () ()

four
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and will handle even if nested parentheses is there.

```
sed -z 's/[^()]*)/)/g' infile
```

Input:

```
( (zero) one ) ( two ) (

three

)

((((nested))here)end) last
four
```

Output:

```
( ()) () ()

(((()))) last
four
```